# How can i divide list according to a threshold?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have such a list and i can separate this list without specify any number. But in those list  difference must be 9 between minimum and maximum number. For example first list should be start with 66 when it comes to 78 another list should be form automatically.

```
 [66.8344897031784,
 68.30329954624176,
 78.08724462985992,
 107.26053655147552,
 107.44138896465302,
 109.66499030590057,
 171.51213765144348,
 172.01367378234863,
 173.17001342773438,
 343.152220249176,
 343.6864709854126,
 346.3593053817749,
 366.87140941619873,
 372.18000888824463,
 376.73717975616455,
 431.0921788215637,
 431.4517140388489,
 431.8779182434082,
 500.0079822540283,
 500.45250415802,
 503.12490463256836]
```

Comment: What have you tried? [Read How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I wrote this code:
**
first_list=[]
first_list.append(ymid[0])
for i in range(len(ymid)-1):
    if ymid[i+1]<(ymid[i]+9):
        first_list.append(ymid[i+1])
        **

Comment: Put that code in the question, please. (use the edit button)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is obviously a trivial homework assignment, I need to be careful not to say too much. I'm going to try to correct your immediate problem, but not post a full solution.

Right now, you're going through the list, checking for deltas less than 9, but you never start a new list. If you check the size of the gap, either it's small enough to add to the list, ELSE you need to start a new list.

Using "else" with your "if" lets you identify when to start a new list.

```
first_list=[] 
first_list.append(ymid[0]) 
for i in range(len(ymid)-1): 
    if ymid[i+1]<(ymid[i]+9): 
        first_list.append(ymid[i+1])
    else:
        # done with this list
        print (first_list)
        # start the new list
        first_list = [ymid[i]]
```

You'll note that the output is incorrect because your loop is wrong, but that's stuff you can fix in debugging. Welcome to programming :)

Since you already handled the first item, should your loop start at 0? Should you be comparing to the next item or the previous one? Once you get it working, check to make sure you handle the last item.

Of course, you can have a list of lists. Instead of just printing each result, you can append to a results list. Just be sure to start a new list for the next grouping.

```
results = []
current_list=[] 
current_list.append(ymid[0]) 
for i in range(len(ymid)-1): 
    if ymid[i+1]<(ymid[i]+9): 
        current_list.append(ymid[i+1])
    else:
        # add current_list to results
        results = current_list
        # start the new list
        current_list = [ymid[i]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much:) here is the problem i cannot figure out how i can add the values through iteration to a list which is not defined before

Comment: so, demonstrate the comment I had in parentheses at the end?